# How to click a button in email to save a file Power Automate

Tags: power-automate

I receive monthly around 200 e-mail like the image in attach, and would like to use power automate to:

- Receive an e-mail from a specific sender;
- The subject contains specific words "ex: invoice";
- Click in a button (link);
- Save the file from that link inside a sharepoint file:
- If possible I would like to save file name as a part of the e-mail subject for example the bold part (XXX Invoice - **R1234/12AA2226-10-22** - )

[image]

I tried some flows without success.

Appreciate if someone can help me :)

I tried some flows in the internet but without success

Comment: What’s your issue? You need to come here with specifics.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need to click a button.  You can trigger a power flow with 'When an email is received' then add a condition - has attachment and subject or body contains = 'invoice'. Use then add step Get Attachments.

Here's a similar flow - but add a condition after step 2 to filter only these types of emails.

[image]

Comment: Hello,

First of all, thanks for your help.

The question is that the email doesn’t have any attachment. It only has that button/hiperlink to then download the invoice.